# .NET Core 2 Authenticate with Azure AD - Custom Login Page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET Core 2.0 Application. At my place of employment, we have an Azure Active Directory tenant. I would like to authenticate my users against that Azure Active Directory instance.

However, while I can find 1000 examples online for how to do it, they all teach exactly the same thing; how to redirect users away from my site, to a boring Microsoft login page, and then back to my app. This is also the default scaffolded code if you choose to "Add Authentication" using the Visual Studio wizard, during a new project's setup.

In addition to being ugly and unbranded, an issue with the Microsoft login page, is that if the user is already signed into their personal account, and then comes to my site, it will say that they do not have permissions to view my site, rather than giving them the option to choose which account to sign in with.

Regardless of my reasoning, I'd like to have a custom login page instead. I was hoping there was a way to gather the user's credentials, and then via an API, authenticate them on the backend.

Does this exist for .NET core 2.0? If so, would someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you are expecting/wanting the wrong thing.

When you offload the user credentials to Azure AD, you also want to be sure that the users only enter their usernames and passwords in the Azure AD sign-in pages.

This is completely the way it is intended. You don't want your users to enter their password in any random page that claims to accept their Azure AD credentials.

With Azure AD it is possible to customize the sign-in page, so it is company branded or otherwise. That customization will be the same for all web apps that let users sign in to your Azure AD.

Comment: So what if I were authenticating against our on-site Active Directory server. Would it be possible then?

Comment: Yes. Enable Windows Authentication in your app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: The same is true for any federated authentication. Imagine if an app used Google authentication, but instead of you logging in to Google, you had to give your Google password to the app?

Comment: @Captainlonate Note that to authenticate against your on-site AD directly (e.g. with Windows Authentication), users will actually need to be on the corporate network. If you suspect that many users will get SSO'd using a user account in the wrong organization (or their personal Microsoft Account), you can consider including `prompt=select_account` in the redirect to Azure AD for sign-in, which will always show the account picker prompt.